# Ubuntu partition table

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I'm having a problem re-arranging my partition table.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQblv.png]

My partition table looks like the picture above,
and I would like to extend my `sda5` to use the space in the `sda4`.
I already tried to format the `sda4` partition to `ext4`, and tried to extend `sda4` to use that space, but no use.
First of all, is there any way to do this without losing my data?
If yes, please guide me how can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to move everything that's in your `sda4` partition into your `sda5` partition, delete `sda4`, extend the extended partition (`sda2`) and finally extend `sda5`.

Because you'll be manipulating the Ubuntu partition, you'll either need to do the partition changes from the Backtrack partition or (recommended) in a live CD/USB. (Note that the data moving in the first step can be done while booted into Ubuntu.)

Also, you may get GRUB boot errors after changing your partition table. To fix this, you'll need to run Boot-Repair from your live CD/USB.